# Adding two array to html5 canvas line chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, linechart

I'm new to Javascript and I have to show 2 ajax arrays in line chart but I couldn't. I got 2 arrays from ajax but I couldn't figure out how to imply those arrays to code.

I only have to use pure javascript and canvas. I saw this link has a good example for me. So, I decided to change it.

https://instructobit.com/tutorial/90/Creating-line-graphs-with-Javascript-using-an-HTML-canvas

I changed it but I could only add one line and this line doesn't look right. Also, my two arrays show the last 7 days' revenue between 10m - 100m. Here is my code.

[picture of my line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQuqa.png)

```
  function drawGraph( dataArr ){
        var canvas = document.getElementById( "testCanvas" );
        var context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

        var GRAPH_TOP = 25;
        var GRAPH_BOTTOM = 375;
        var GRAPH_LEFT = 25;
        var GRAPH_RIGHT = 475;

        var GRAPH_HEIGHT = 350;
        var GRAPH_WIDTH = 450;

        var arrayLen = dataArr.length;

        var largest = 0;
        for( var i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++ ){
            if( dataArr[ i ] > largest ){
                largest = dataArr[ i ];
            }
        }

        context.clearRect( 0, 0, 500, 400 );
        // set font for fillText()
        context.font = "16px Arial";

        // draw X and Y axis
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo( GRAPH_LEFT, GRAPH_BOTTOM );
        context.lineTo( GRAPH_RIGHT, GRAPH_BOTTOM );
        context.lineTo( GRAPH_RIGHT, GRAPH_TOP );
        context.stroke();

        // draw reference line
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "#BBB";
        context.moveTo( GRAPH_LEFT, GRAPH_TOP );
        context.lineTo( GRAPH_RIGHT, GRAPH_TOP );
        // draw reference value for hours
        context.fillText( largest, GRAPH_RIGHT + 15, GRAPH_TOP);
        context.stroke();

        // draw reference line
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo( GRAPH_LEFT, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT ) / 4 * 3 + GRAPH_TOP );
        context.lineTo( GRAPH_RIGHT, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT ) / 4 * 3 + GRAPH_TOP );
        // draw reference value for hours
        context.fillText( largest / 4, GRAPH_RIGHT + 15, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT ) / 4 * 3 + GRAPH_TOP);
        context.stroke();

        // draw reference line
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo( GRAPH_LEFT, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT ) / 2 + GRAPH_TOP );
        context.lineTo( GRAPH_RIGHT, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT ) / 2 + GRAPH_TOP );
        // draw reference value for hours
        context.fillText( largest / 2, GRAPH_RIGHT + 15, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT ) / 2 + GRAPH_TOP);
        context.stroke();

        // draw reference line
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo( GRAPH_LEFT, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT ) / 4 + GRAPH_TOP );
        context.lineTo( GRAPH_RIGHT, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT ) / 4 + GRAPH_TOP );
        // draw reference value for hours
        context.fillText( largest / 4 * 3, GRAPH_RIGHT + 15, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT ) / 4 + GRAPH_TOP);
        context.stroke();

        // draw titles
        context.fillText( "Revenue Last 7 days", GRAPH_RIGHT / 3, GRAPH_BOTTOM + 50);
        context.fillText( "Hours", GRAPH_RIGHT + 30, GRAPH_HEIGHT / 2);

        context.beginPath();
        context.lineJoin = "round";
        context.strokeStyle = "black";

        context.moveTo( GRAPH_LEFT, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT - dataArr[ 0 ] / largest * GRAPH_HEIGHT ) + GRAPH_TOP );
        // draw reference value for day of the week
        context.fillText( "1", 15, GRAPH_BOTTOM + 25);
        for( var i = 1; i < arrayLen; i++ ){
            context.lineTo( GRAPH_RIGHT / arrayLen * i + GRAPH_LEFT, ( GRAPH_HEIGHT - dataArr[ i ] / largest * GRAPH_HEIGHT ) + GRAPH_TOP );
            // draw reference value for day of the week
            context.fillText( ( i + 1 ), GRAPH_RIGHT / arrayLen * i, GRAPH_BOTTOM + 25);
        }
        context.stroke();
    }

    drawGraph(myfirstarray);
```

Comment: do you interested with using external javascript ? like chart.js? it looks also awesome if you ok I can help to do....

Comment: I did it with chart.js and canvas.js before this effort but I have to do with pure javascript and canvas because javascript frameworks have latency in my show screen.

Comment: I used google chart instead. It claims it supports ie9 and above. So, I gave it a try.